# Extend a Div the Length of it's Container

Tags: css, html, extend

I am trying to extend my left sidebar so that it spans the length of the page (or the container DIV). I tried setting the height of the container to 100% and then the height of the sidebar to 100%, but that did not work.

Here is my coding:

```
div#container
{
overflow: hidden;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 0px;    
padding-bottom: 10px;
width: 880px;   
height: 100%;
text-align: left;
}

div#left
{
float: left;
width: 280px;
height: 100%;   
padding: 4px;   
background: #F1D7A5;
}
```

And here is what the page looks like: http://www.studentbridges.org/new/

Any input on how I can extend the sidebar would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

~Noelle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usualy solve this problem by putting the background of the sidebar as an image on the container of the sidebar, and repeating it along the y-axis. This does not actualy strectch your sidebar, but it looks the same. 
In your case you could just take a printscreen of your page as it is now, crop it to 1px height and 880px width, and setting it as the background of your `#container`:

```
background: url(<path_to_image>) repeat-y center;
```

You can also remove the background from `#left` then.
Everything to avoid using tables!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the height to 100% restricts the height of the container. If you set the container to the pixel height you'd like it to be, the sub-div will extend its height to match. Because your lower div is a sub-div of its container, height: 100% will only result to the remaining length left in the container div, as you can see.

Comment: But the container has a variable length based on what page someone is viewing. And still, the container is longer than the siebar even though the sidebar is set to 100%.

Maybe I'm not understanding you.

Comment: your #left div not directly inside #container, it is inside #contbg inside #container, and #contbg is only given what space of #container is not occupied by #header.

Comment: Oh. I thought if I set them all to 100%, it would extend down the page. I guess not.

Do you know how I can remedy this? Or am I just fresh out of luck?

Comment: you can put the #left div directly inside the #container div.. but if you want the #left div to be to the left of your content I would probably make a table within you #container with columns #left, #(rest of #container)

Comment: The issue there is that the contbg div is what is making the background color yellow. And I really didn't want to resort to using tables... uggg. Thank you though!

Comment: If this solved your question, please remember to vote or select an answer