# How can I make a div's height 100%

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing a sidebar. I would like the sidebar's height to be 100% (of the parent div). For now it is only high as the content it has.

```
#parent {
    height: 100%;
}    
#sidebar {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You will have to show the relevant HTML and CSS so we can see how the layout works in order to answer.  Ideally, you'd put a simple example in a jsFiddle.

Comment: eq by jquery $('#parent,#sidebar').css('min-height', $(window).height() ); + bind or resize

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694856/extend-a-div-the-length-of-its-container/11705728#11705728

Comment: 100% height only works inside an element whose height is already known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the height to 100%, it's 100% of what? The parent might be set to 100% but what quantity is that? While html is set to the height of the viewport, your parent div must be set to something with a set height in real numbers, or inherit it from its parent.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities to realise this.

The easiest way is to set the height of `<html>` and `<body>` to `100%`.

**HTML**

```
<div id=parent>
    <div id=sidebar></div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{height:100%}
#parent {
    height: 100%;
    background: #222 /* not needed */
}    
#sidebar {
    width: 200px; /* not needed */
    height: 100%;
    background: #444 /* not needed */
}​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5tazc/)

**EDIT**

`overflow:auto` fixes the problem too height content:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5tazc/2/)**

Comment: this causes problems when the content becvomes bigger then 100%. http://jsfiddle.net/5tazc/1/

Comment: If you look at http://gablabelle.com you will see the sidebar is still not 100% maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Okay! I Accept... I think it's the best way to delete the height properties for your sidebar and content!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry 100% only apply to width does not apply to height you can try a jquery approach instead

```
html_height = $("#parent").height();
$('#sidebar').height(html_height);
```

with this unless you have a padding/margin on the side bar the height should be okay